# Are there examples of deprecated HTML elements that lost support in current browsers?

Tags: html, deprecated

Most of us know that now and then some tags get a deprecated status, which means that it has been outdated. Either it is followed by a newer HTML construct, or it can be done in CSS (take for example `<center>`). The question that I'm wondering about, though, is: when a tag or element gets deprecated will it be removed from browser support in the future? In other words, currently all browsers that I know of support `<center>`, but I can imagine that it might not be efficient for browsers to keep supporting deprecated content. Therefore, support must drop after some time.

Is it likely that browsers drop support for a tag or element that once was quite common? To provide a question that's better suited for the SO question-answer template, I'll rephrase all of the above: **are cases known where browsers have dropped support for a property or element that once was common?**

The only thing that I could find was in [the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/conform.html), stating:

> **Deprecated** A deprecated element or attribute is one that has been outdated by newer constructs. Deprecated elements are defined in the
> reference manual in appropriate locations, but are clearly marked as
> deprecated. Deprecated elements may become obsolete in future versions
> of HTML.
>
> *User agents should continue to support deprecated elements for reasons of backward compatibility.*
>
> Definitions of elements and attributes clearly indicate which are
> deprecated.

As I see it, this is *not* opinion based. I am asking if there are cases known of tags that are actually not being supported by browsers any more. That's not bound by opinion. However I do understand that this question has quite an open feel to it. Therefore I'd like to clarify that I am looking for actual and factual evidence of browsers dropping support. I'm not asking about any foreseers to come forward and confess their magical powers, I'm merely looking for examples from cases that have occurred in the past.

Comment: It says it right there in the documentation: "Deprecated elements **may become obsolete** in future versions of HTML". We can't predict the future, so there's no way for us to know if or when individual browser vendors will drop support for a deprecated element or tag unless they announce it.

Comment: @TylerH any examples of already obsoleted ?

Comment: Re: edit, if you are asking of **past** examples, then you need to change your question title, which is asking about **future** examples.

Comment: why would you care if I may ask?

Comment: @TylerH I rephrased my question. Even though I'm interested in the discussion whether or not browser builders will drop support, I changed the question to whether this has happened in the past. That's a factual question and therefore not opinion-based.

Comment: @vsync I am a curious man.

Comment: but any logical thinking will tell you it just cannot be known. there is no answer to this. there are no rules to these type of things. nothing that can be looked at "statistically"

Comment: @vsync I suppose you mean that my question is primarily opinion based. As I told TylerH I rephrased my question, and now I'm only asking for factual evidence.

Comment: There is a big difference between WC3 recommendations, basically they are governing HTML, and companies that build web browsers. Things that are deprecated in WC3 standards (or removed) can be long supported by browser vendors(e.g, code may not be passing WC3 html or css validator but still works perfectly in browsers). And some stuff from WC3 not being supported by vendors, like CSS3 print module.

Comment: for example, the <isindex> tag was removed in HTML4 (was a thing in HTML3.2). Also the <basefont> tag iirc doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @IGRACH I'm aware that W3C (mind the spelling) is not the same as browser builders. My question, therefore, concerns how browser builders deal with the proclaimed authority and decisions of W3C.

Comment: Deprecation is a long and slow process, it doesn't happen overnight, if anything major will be removed it will be announced in advance.

Comment: While the `<isindex>` *tag* is still processed by HTML5 parsers (it produces a set of elements not a single one) I think `<blink>` might be what you are looking for. It was widely supported by browsers of the past, but not by modern browsers.

Comment: you can use or make up tags. the "deprecated" thing only means that they are to be canceled, hence, not having any official default style or purpose. so, are you asking if their default styles would disappear?

Comment: @Bram Vanroy sorry for spelling to many years of playing WC3 xd

Comment: Not yet deprecated, but [Opera doesn't support the `<noscript>` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4525009/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi: There is absolutely no reason to deprecate `noscript` and it's very clear from one of the answers that this wasn't intentional. In fact, it was only broken in one specific version and fixed in the next.

Comment: I don't know if melding deprecated HTML elements and CSS properties into one question is a good idea. They are two totally different things, even if they both go through deprecation processes.

Comment: @BoltClock I edited my post accordingly. I also voted to re-open because as I see it, and as Rick Hitchcock's answer below proves, it is very well possible to answer this question on a strictly factual basis.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code below creates elements from deprecated tags, and it outputs what the browser thinks the newly-created elements really are:

```js
var dep = 'acronym|applet|basefont|bgsound|big|blink|center|dir|font|frame|frameset|hgroup|isindex|listing|marquee|menu|multicol|nextid|nobr|noembed|noframes|plaintext|s|spacer|strike|tt|u|xmp'.split('|'),
  s = '<table>',
  els = [];

dep.forEach(function(val) {
  var el = document.createElement(val),
    str = el.toString().slice(8, -1),
    style = 'HTMLElement HTMLPhraseElement HTMLBlockElement HTMLPreElement HTMLSpanElement HTMLDivElement'.indexOf(str) > -1 ? 'background:yellow' :
    str === 'HTMLUnknownElement' ? 'background:orange' :
    '';
  el.innerHTML = val;
  els.push(el);
  s += '<tr style="' + style + '">' +
    '<td>' + val +
    '<td>' + str +
    '<td>';
});

s += '</table>';
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = s;

var td = document.querySelectorAll('td:last-child');
dep.forEach(function(val, idx) {
  td[idx].appendChild(els[idx]);
});
```

```css
table {
  font: 12px verdana;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

We can assume that anything highlighted in orange is *not* supported by that browser, anything highlighted in yellow is iffy, and the rest should be completely supported.

---

To determine the degree of "iffyness" of the generic "HTMLElements," we could compare their default CSS styles to the default styles of a `span` or `div` element.  The Snippet below does this by adding a new column to the listing, which shows styles distinct to each deprecated element.

Elements of type "HTMLUnknownElement" have no distinct styles (as expected).  Most other elements do.  For those that don't, that doesn't necessarily mean they don't support distinct *attributes*.  For example, the `font` element's styles match the default styles of a `span` – but the `font` element supports attributes `size` and `face`, which the `span` does *not* support.

```js
function getStyles(el) {
  var gcs= getComputedStyle(el),
      st= gcs.cssText ? gcs.cssText.split(/; */) : el.currentStyle,
      obj= {},
      i, j, sp;
    
  for(var i = 0 ; i < st.length ; i++) {
    sp= st[i].split(':')[0];
    if(j = gcs.getPropertyValue(sp)) {
      obj[sp]= j;
    }
  }
  return obj;
} //getStyles

function compStyles(st1, st2) {
  var s= '';
  for(var i in st1) {
    if(st1[i] && st1[i] !== st2[i]) {
      s+= i+': '+st1[i]+' - '+st2[i]+'; ';
    }
  }
  return s;
} //compStyles

var dep= 'acronym|applet|basefont|bgsound|big|blink|center|dir|font|frame|frameset|hgroup|isindex|listing|marquee|menu|multicol|nextid|nobr|noembed|noframes|plaintext|spacer|strike|tt|xmp'.split('|'),
    s= '<table>',
    els= [],
    spanStyles=
      getStyles(
        document.body.appendChild(
          document.createElement('span')
        )
      ),
    divStyles=
      getStyles(
        document.body.appendChild(
          document.createElement('div')
        )
      );

dep.forEach(function(val) {
  var el= document.createElement(val),
      str= el.toString().slice(8,-1),
      display,
      style= 'HTMLElement HTMLPhraseElement HTMLBlockElement HTMLPreElement HTMLSpanElement HTMLDivElement'.indexOf(str)>-1 ? 'background:yellow' :
             str==='HTMLUnknownElement' ? 'background:orange' :
             '';

  document.body.appendChild(el);
  display= getStyles(el).display;
    
  el.innerHTML= val;
  els.push(el);
  s+= '<tr style="'+style+'">'+
        '<td>'+val+
        '<td>'+str+
        '<td>'+display+
        '<td>'+compStyles(
                 getStyles(el),
                 display==='block' ? divStyles : spanStyles
               )+
        '<td>';
  
});

s+= '</table>';
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML= s;

var td= document.querySelectorAll('td:last-child');
dep.forEach(function(val, idx) {
  td[idx].appendChild(els[idx]);
});
```

```css
table {
  font: 12px verdana;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: `s` and `u` are no longer deprecated - like `b` and `i`, they have been repurposed in HTML5.

Comment: Yes, good point.  A number of non-deprecated tags also return as the generic "HTMLElement," so the only assumption we can really make is that the ones in orange are not supported.

Comment: This looks very nice. I slightly edited your fiddle so it was visually more clear to me which elements gave what output in the browser. You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ezqmv1bo/1/).

Comment: That's a really nice improvement.  You could also put them within the listing:  http://jsfiddle.net/ezqmv1bo/2/.   I've got some ideas for determining the "iffyness" of the "HTMLElement" tags.  I need to test those out.

Comment: Ah yes, that's even better. Very nice!

Comment: Now updated, though this is certainly not the final word on the question.

Answer (score 7):

It has happened before.

The `<blink>` HTML tag ([see wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element) and [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink)) used to be quite common, but it was considered very user-unfriendly and therefore became deprecated. Netscape, Opera and also Firefox used to support it. Firefox was the last to finally completely remove it in version 23.

The `<blink>` element was exceptionally obtrusive and became very unpopular, so the drop in support was no surprise... but it  is also a question of backwards compatibility. Do the benefits of removing something outweigh the loss of its functionality? `<blink>` could be removed without much repercussion (things would just stop blinking). On the other hand, a tag like `<marquee>` (which has also received a lot of negative press) is still supported, most likely because removing it may effect content directly.

All in all I think that the issue isn't really if existing browsers will remove deprecated css/html (since it is a relatively rare occurrence), but rather whether new/future browsers will support them. Backwards compatibility will only go so far.

To sum up: **Yes, so don't use deprecated features.**

Comment: ah <blink>  and <marquee>  those were the days.

Comment: @JoelAnderson So true, I miss my seizure-inducing designs. Good times... good times.

Comment: I loved when I used `<marquee>` for the first time and letters star moving on my browser that was a good experience :D. looong time ago. And if I remember IExplorer stop supporting `<blink>` long time ago actually before `netscape`.